# Getting the total samples of an audio file using ffmpeg.exe in C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I'm currently working on a C# project where I need to determine the total number of samples in an audio file using ffmpeg.exe. I've been attempting to achieve this by executing the ffmpeg.exe command within my C# code and parsing the output, but I haven't been successful so far.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class AudioUtils
{
    public static int GetTotalSamples(string audioFilePath)
    {
        string ffmpegPath = "path/to/ffmpeg.exe"; // Path to ffmpeg.exe

        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = ffmpegPath,
            Arguments = $"-i \"{audioFilePath}\" -af \"volumedetect\" -vn -sn -dn -f null /dev/null 2>&1",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        string output = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();

        int totalSamples = 0;
        // Parsing logic to extract total samples from output goes here...

        return totalSamples;
    }
}
```

I suspect there might be an issue with the command or the parsing logic in the code snippet above. Could someone please guide me on how to correctly execute ffmpeg.exe and extract the total number of samples from the output in C#? Any insights, alternative approaches, or modifications to the code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!